# How to connect Android studio with emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I am building an Android project now. BTW have no Android phone(just iPhone). So I had to use any type of Emulator for this.

Now I get LdPlayer(emulator) and Android Studio. Is there any connect Android studio with Emulator? (Don't want Android AVD because heavy and slow.)

Thanks, advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Follow steps:

1. Click "setting" button.
2. Select "Other settings".
3. Drop-down and select "Open remote connection" in ADB debugging.
4. "Save settings".

And run android studio and select device to LDPlayer to emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this emulator : https://www.genymotion.com/
Simple,Fast and Scalable emulator for android.

Comment: I didn't try with genymotion before. but will be helpful when i get it. Thanks for your recommend!